# In my Flutter code file.readAsLines() is not working

Tags: flutter, dart

I have simple function in my Flutter project to read files from a text file. It uses the file.readAsLines() function. The function is as follows -

```
void readFileByLines() {  
  File file = new File('D:/textDemo11.txt');
  file.readAsLines().then((lines) {
    for (int i = 0; i < lines.length; i++) {
      print(lines[i]);
    }
  });
}
```

Even thought the file exists in the path used in the function it throws the following exception --
*[ERROR:flutter/runtime/dart_vm_initializer.cc(41)] Unhandled Exception: PathNotFoundException: Cannot open file, path = 'D:/textDemo11.txt' (OS Error: No such file or directory, errno = 2)*

**However when I use the same function in a Dart project with the same path, it works fine there**
I expect it to simply read and print the lines.

Comment: where do you run that flutter project? is it flutter desktop for windows (https://flutter.dev/multi-platform/desktop) ?

Comment: If you're getting the error when running in an Android emulator, then the error is correct since no file with that path would exist on the emulated device.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

as the others already mentioned: I think you are getting the error because you are running the app on a device (or simulator or emulator) from where your hard drive D cannot be accessed.